# Removing Files from iTunes Media?

Tags: itunes, pc

I noticed that I have well over 100 songs in the iTunes Media folder that are NOT in my actual iTunes. These would be songs that were loaded into iTunes then deleted because I didn't like them, want them, whatever. They are taking up hard drive space and I want to flush them out w/o having to go into each and every single folder and finding the songs that are not in my iTunes. I would have to sort through over 6,000 files to do that. There has to be an easier way! Thank you!

I wanted to add that I am using a PC (Windows 7) and not a MAC.

Answer (score 2):

One of the many useful scripts in [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) is [Music Folder Files Not Added](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=musicfolderfilesnotadded2), which will do exactly what you're looking for. Just download and run it, and it will give you a list of all files in your iTunes folders that aren't in the library.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but I failed to mention I am on a PC and it says it won't run on my system.

Comment: Hi, has anyone found something like this that will work on a PC?